# Java Jdeveloper

Tags: java, timezone, jdeveloper, dst

When I run the following java code in JDeveloper, I get the wrong output. What can be the reasons for that?

```
    System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney").inDaylightTime(new Date()));
    System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow").inDaylightTime(new Date()));
```

I am expecting an output as:
true
false

But, I am getting it as:
false
true

PS: This is working correct for few other time zones like "America/Fort_Wayne" and "Europe/Berlin".

Comment: Is the date on your computer wrong? http://ideone.com/BPhYKq gives true false

Comment: No. The date on my computer is correct and it is in Fort Wayne timezone. I changed it to UTC and still got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the use of `new Date()` is not fully following the principle of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), here it is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date = new Date(1444817534489L); // 2015-10-14 10:12:14.489 UTC
    printDate(date, "UTC");
    printDate(date, "Australia/Sydney");
    printDate(date, "Europe/Moscow");
    printDate(date, "Europe/Berlin");
    printDate(date, "America/Fort_Wayne");
}
private static void printDate(Date date, String timeZoneID) {
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneID);
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z");
    df.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    System.out.printf("%-20s %-30s inDaylightTime: %s%n", timeZoneID + ":",
                      df.format(date), timeZone.inDaylightTime(date));
}
```

*Output*

```
UTC:                 2015-10-14 10:12:14.489 UTC    inDaylightTime: false
Australia/Sydney:    2015-10-14 21:12:14.489 AEDT   inDaylightTime: true
Europe/Moscow:       2015-10-14 13:12:14.489 MSK    inDaylightTime: false
Europe/Berlin:       2015-10-14 12:12:14.489 CEST   inDaylightTime: true
America/Fort_Wayne:  2015-10-14 06:12:14.489 EDT    inDaylightTime: true
```

So, `true false` as you expected. If you saw different, maybe your date was different, and without printing it, how would you know?

Comment: But, my output is as follows: `code`15/10/14 10:47:13 UTC : 2015-10-14 10:12:14.489 UTC inDaylightTime: false
15/10/14 10:47:13 Australia/Sydney : 2015-10-14 20:12:14.489 EST inDaylightTime: false
15/10/14 10:47:13 Europe/Moscow : 2015-10-14 14:12:14.489 MSD inDaylightTime: true
15/10/14 10:47:13 Europe/Berlin : 2015-10-14 12:12:14.489 CEST inDaylightTime: true
15/10/14 10:47:13 America/Fort_Wayne : 2015-10-14 06:12:14.489 EDT inDaylightTime: true`code`

Comment: The 'z' value for "Australia/Sydney" Time Zone id in my output is 'EST' instead of 'AEDT'. Similarly, the 'z' value for "Europe/Moscow" Time Zone id is 'MSD' instead of 'MSK'. What can be the cause for this? Is it somehow related to java version?

Comment: Sure. What version are you running? I am running jdk1.8.0_51, 64-bit, on Win7.

Comment: I am running the Web Service on an Embedded OC4J Server in JDeveloper. The Project Properties says that the J2SE version is 1.5.0_06. Is this the version you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah. and that's *ancient*, like more than 10 years old, so its TimeZone database is out-of-date.

Comment: @Andreas 1.5.0_09 was released around 2006-10 so merely 9 years old :)

Comment: OK. I will check on that right away. Thank you so much. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I was not in a position to update my java version. So, I found a tool called TZUpdater in the Oracle website which updated the Time Zones related information in my current java version. [link] (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/timezones-137583.html)